# Audit on @Embeddable objects with SpringBoot annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, auditing

I want to use SpringData annotations from package *org.springframework.data.annotation*

```
@CreatiedOn
@CreatedBy
@ModifiedOn
@ModifiedBy
```

My configuration is as well:

```
@Embeddable
public class AuditFields {

    @Column({...})
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @Column({...})
    @CreatedDate
    private Instant createdOn;

    @Column({...})
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String updatedBy;

    @Column({...})
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant updatedOn;
```

... And the `AuditFileds` is applied as composition:

```
@Entity    
public class A {

   {...}
 
   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable({...})
   private Collection<B> b;

   @Embedded
   private AuditFields auditFields = new AuditFields();

}
```

and

```
@Embeddable  
public class B {

   {...}

   @Embedded
   private AuditFields auditFields = new AuditFields();

}
```

... and I also have configured `@EnableJpaAuditing` bean

The framework works perfect when persists `class A` and the `@Entity` object has been successfully audited, but nothing happens on `class B` which is `@Embeddable` collection (record B is not audited into the table).

Any ideas why SpringData audit neglect `@Embeddable` collection? Is it problem in SpringData?

Any ideas for another aproach how to audit `@Embeddable` collection?

`spring-data-jpa` is version `2.7.15`.